# Bit-length of Key in Charm-Crypto

Tags: python, cryptography, charm-crypto

I'm using **Charm-Crypto** to understand the CP-ABE scheme. I'm testing this scheme: *CPabe_BSW07Test*. This is the code:

```
from charm.schemes.abenc.abenc_bsw07 import CPabe_BSW07
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,GT
import unittest
class CPabe_BSW07Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCPabe_BSW07(self):    
        groupObj = PairingGroup('SS512')

        cpabe = CPabe_BSW07(groupObj)

        attrs = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
        access_policy = '((four or three) and (three or one))'
        if debug: 
            print("Attributes =>", attrs); print("Policy =>", access_policy)

        (pk, mk) = cpabe.setup()

        sk = cpabe.keygen(pk, mk, attrs)

        print (groupObj)

        rand_msg = groupObj.random(GT) 
        if debug: print("msg =>", rand_msg)
        ct = cpabe.encrypt(pk, rand_msg, access_policy)
        if debug: print("\n\nCiphertext...\n")
        groupObj.debug(ct) 

        rec_msg = cpabe.decrypt(pk, sk, ct)
        if debug: print("\n\nDecrypt...\n")
        if debug: print("Rec msg =>", rec_msg)

        assert rand_msg == rec_msg, "FAILED Decryption: message is incorrect"
        if debug: print("Successful Decryption!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I want to understand how can I calculate the bit lenght of a Private Key. I know the formula (in this [paper](http://www.ijmetmr.com/oldecember2015/Mazin-MohammedKhaleelAhmed-A-84.pdf) **BSW**), but I want to check if it is true. For example if have a curve defined on 512 bit, and I have 10 attributes, the key bit-length is: (2*10+1)*512=10752 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSW07 uses a pairing of `e: G0 x G0 → G1`, which corresponds to `G1 x G1 → GT` in Charm. The secret key consists of `2*n+1` elements of `G1` for `n` attributes.

A single element `g` can be serialized with

```
groupObj.serialize(g)
```

which results in a Base64 encoded string. Something like this for SS512:

```
b'1:Nri028S0SySkDoN0JH1Lu6HQo/Jkhq7DCZHI1MUrHOuIgCONonN14GzmhwopYQOxnjOysclhYNOnsvCLjVDLggE='
```

This string has `65` (decoded) byte in it (one of which denotes the sign of the element), which corresponds to 512 bit without sign.

If you want to deserialize the string representation, you can use

```
groupObj.deserialize(b64String)
```

The actual size might be different depending on whether you really want to store this Base64 representation or convert it yourself to binary.

---

[Documentation](http://jhuisi.github.io/charm/toolbox/pairinggroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic way is to generate the private key(s) (keygen), serialize, and then count the bit length with len().